# Issue mounting drives to specified path

Tags: mount

I'm struggling with this one.  I have 8 data drives connected via USB3 in a tower.  Yesterday, all drives were mounting just fine.  But then I started changing the mount point for all the drives.

Issue: 6 of the drives mount just fine.  The other 2 mount to any path I specify EXCEPT the path I want them to mount to.  For example, I have one drive with a few shows on it.  I'm trying to mount it to /mnt/shows1.  When I do this, whether via gui or terminal, there's no error given, it just won't mount.  But if I change it to /mnt/shows or /mnt/shows2, there's no issue.

Obviously the workaround is to just use a different mount point, but I'm trying to fix the problem, not work around it.

Any ideas?  I'm a bit of a Linux noob.  Thank you!

Comment: EDIT: Using Ubuntu 20.04.1

Comment: You can use the edit feature to edit your question. Click here to edit your question: [edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ahh, the old "It was working fine, but now I fixed it and it doesn't work at all" scenario. You clearly have a future in helpdesk support!

In this instance I would reboot the Ubuntu server. It's possible that there is a stale record left in the mount tables somewhere.

Let us see what the following give us:

> df              # This lists disks that are mounted
> cat /etc/fstab  # This lists the disks in the file system table
> cat /etc/mtab   # This lists disks that the system thinks are mounted

Comment: I know!  I'm so ashamed!

Comment: Ok, I'm such a noob, I can't figure out how to post results; too many characters.

Comment: To summarize, df # listed all drives and mount points but NOT the 2 in question (neither device, nor mount point)

cat /etc/fstab #   seemed to show both as if they were working nomally, right device mounted to the desired mount point

cat /etc/mtab #    neither device/mount point in question listed here either

Comment: And you helped me find the answer - thanks!  Turns out there was an old entry in fstab I hadn't noticed that prevented them from being mounted properly.  Thanks for helping me out!